# How to change default page of odoo with other webcontroller odoo 9.0

Tags: html, odoo-9

I have created a new webcontroller with specific functionality and I want this webcontroller as a home page of `odoo 9.0`.

I have tried to put `@http.route('/', type='http', auth='public', website=True)` in `main.py` of my custom webcontroller file as a route, but still it redirect to default home page of odoo.

But if I put url as `@http.route('/index', type='http', auth='public', website=True)`, the page is working fine.

So my question is what is best way to replace existing odoo home page with custom controller or module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from openerp import http
from openerp.addons.website.controllers.main import Website

class Website(Website):
    @http.route(auth='public')
    def index(self, data={},**kw):
        super(Website, self).index(**kw)
        return http.request.render('<your_addon>.<your_template_id>', data)
```

Comment: Phillip, you are amazing. It works for me. Home page has replaced with my content now. I have also noticed one this, the website is multilingual, when I change the language, it again redirect to previous home page and url is something like "fr_FR/page/homepage". Is there anything we need to do for multilingual url as well? Please suggest.

Comment: Sorry @Prawez I have not used the multi language features myself. I imagine it would be quite similar. What did you have in mind for the path leading to the alternate languages?

Comment: I have tried the same way to override the **@http.route('/page/<page:page>', type='http', auth="public", website=True)** method from Website module to my custom module, but it gives me 500 internal error every time. Is there any other way to override this method?

Comment: You may want to open another question. Post your code, describe what you wish to accomplish and display the errors you find in the logs when trying to implement your code.

Comment: Does this work differently for v 10?  Granted one has to change small things like `from openerp` to `from odoo` etc .. but other than that, I get no errors but the custom controller is never called.

Comment: I have found you have to make slight variations from version of Odoo to version of Odoo.

Comment: @PhillipStack I went ahead and posted a separate question then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57083803/how-to-implement-custom-controller-for-odoo-10-that-overides-default-controller