# Overriding index method of Website module in Odoo 11

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

I am trying to override index method in website module in odoo 11.

Following is my code

```
from odoo import http
from addons.website.controllers.main import Website


class Home(Website):

@http.route(['/', '/index', '/home'], type='http', website=True, auth='public')
def index(self, **kw):
    super(Website, self).index(**kw)
    return http.request.render('my_website.home')
```

I have created a new template in my_website named home.
But when I go to **http://localhost:8069** it is loading the standard odoo template for website with header and footer.
When I go to either http://localhost:8069/index or http://localhost:8069/home it is throwing 404 error. It doesn't take my new template home.

I have referred this SO question [How to change default page of odoo with other webcontroller odoo 9.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195759/how-to-change-default-page-of-odoo-with-other-webcontroller-odoo-9-0) but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is solved. You have to import from **odoo.addons** rather from **addons**.

```
from odoo.addons.web.controllers.main import Website


class MyHome(Website):

@http.route(['/', '/index', '/home'], type='http', website=True, auth='public')
def index(self, **kw):
    return http.request.render('my_website.home')
```

Then use your template to render.