# How to implement custom controller for Odoo 10 that overides default controller

Tags: odoo-10

I need to access the /web/session/authenticate method (from Vue app) in Odoo 10 but I need to make a tiny customization. [Based on another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195759/how-to-change-default-page-of-odoo-with-other-webcontroller-odoo-9-0) I can see that it should be possible to over-ride Odoo's built in controllers so I have this in a custom controller, in a custom module:

```
from odoo import http
from odoo.http import request
from odoo.addons.web.controllers.main import Session

class Session(Session):

    @http.route('/web/session/authenticate', type='json', auth="none", cors="*")
    def authenticate(self, db, login, password, base_location=None):
        print("custom authentication method called")

        request.session.authenticate(db, login, password)
        return request.env['ir.http'].session_info()
```

When compared with the [existing source code](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py#L749), one can see that all I am doing is adding CORS support (needed for my axios POST in the Vue app to that route)

I'm not getting errors, but for some reason my custom code is never called by Odoo. Perhaps this has something to do with the order in which my modules are loading?

Comment: Also ..keep in mind that at this point, there is no DB context because there is no session. I have noticed Odoo uses the "nodb_routing_map" to determine valid routes when no DB is known and db_monodb() cannot determine the DB. So maybe this also prevents ANY controllers working in custom modules??

Answer (score 0):

By default Odoo will not know that the custom module with the custom controller needs to be used if the HTTP request does not have a DB specified in the session.

To work around this, one makes the custom module, a "server-wide module". Which means that its used in the entire context of the server, and not just in context of a database (which is part of the session info). This is done with either adding `--load=web,your_module_here` or adding this to the Odoo config: `server_wide_modules = web,your_module_here`.

Note, if you don't have `web` as one of the server-wide modules, everything will end up with 404 responses. `web` is the default server-wide module in Odoo